# OpenSSL 3.x Migration from DH_meth_set_bn_mod_exp() to provider architecture

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

We have a custom implementation for computing the Diffie Hellman key that uses hardware acceleration.  We had been using DH_meth_set_bn_mod_exp() to register the acceleration function.   As of OpenSSL3.0 this function (as well as others) has been deprecated.

The documentation is very sketchy on this and makes a generic reference to moving to provider architecture.

Can somebody provide me some hint as to how we might offer DH acceleration across all of the services that might use this?

Thanks in advance.

We are migrating an engine that installs this hook into openssl.   We need to preserve this hardware acceleration and be compatible with the new APIs.